# .current_user not working when using scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-scope

I'm using Devise and has_scope gem for filtering options and only want show a current users links only.

**This works**

```
@links = current_user.links.all
```

**This does not. Can someone explain what i need to do to make this work?**

```
@links = apply_scopes(Link).current_user.all
```

Comment: current_user is just a method that returns a user object so you cannot call i like this way you just can try current_user.apply_scopes(Link).all but in fact i'm not sure, just give it a try.

Comment: Tried that but then i get undefined method for apply_scopes.

Comment: It makes sense because User model does not have an instance method called apply_scopes. :/

Comment: One work around is to create a scope in the link that takes an argument user_id and in your controller pass a default value for that scope with current_user.id. I'm not familiar with has_scope syntax but from their doc, logically it will definitely work, hope it helps.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a example on how to do that would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a scope in the link that takes an argument user_id and in your controller has_scope with no arguments, and just pass a hash to apply_scopes method to override the supplied values of your scope.

## Link Model

```
scope :of_user,->(user_id){ where(user_id: user_id)}
```

## Link Controller

```
has_scope :of_user
```

Just call **apply_scopes(Link, of_user: current_user.id).all** where of_user is just the applied params for the named scope.

Comment: I get "undefined local variable or method current_user"

Comment: ok i figured it out try apply_scopes(Link, of_user: current_user.id).all and just has_scope :of_user, if every thing is ok (Tested on rails 3) I will edit my answer otherwise i will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following pattern to apply for ownership:

**Model**

```
scope :by_owner, ->(user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
```

**Controller**

```
has_scope :by_owner, allow_blank: true,
  default: ->(controller){ controller.current_user } do |controller, scope|
    scope.by_owner(controller.current_user.id)
  end
```

The `by_owner` scope is applied by default. No need to add any additional scopes to your action.

An example:

```
def index
  render json: apply_scopes(Link)
end
```